# Openshift : getting rid of HTTP"S" for good

Tags: http, ssl, https, openshift

I wanted to get help on this issue of mine.
Openshift is using https by default on its free applications,
whereas Heroku is using http
Whenever a visitor visits my website, he is presented with an Unsecure Connection warning.

How can we get rid of this warning or https altogether once and for all.

I am fine with http alone as
I am not willing to upgrade to silver for SSL thing only.
Nor do i have an SSL cert with me, am not planning on buying one.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

strange thing I am also deploying my applications on openshift and they all are on http server. What ate the cartridges you are using??

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift does not use https by default, we allow both http & https for free accounts and paid accounts.  it may be something in your framework that you are using that is causing the redirect to https, it could also be that you visited the app before it was completely setup, and got redirected to https://app-domain.rhcloud.com/app, and now your browser is stuck on the https redirect.  Try clearing your cache, test with another browser, or check the framework you are using to make sure it's not redirecting to https.